# MapKit Show Entire Globe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I am trying to draw the entire globe inside my MKMapView.  By pinching to zoom out I am limited to zooming out to a certain level.  I would like to be able to zoom out past this level to show the entire globe on the map.  This doesn't seem like it would be very difficult, but I have been unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map inside an `MKMapView` doesn't repats on the sides, so you can't zoom out far enough to view the whole world.
Solution: Write your own renderer (very hard task, working with coordinates on a surface like the earth is a pain).

Comment: Well here is what I don't really get about your answer.  If I rotate my application into landscape mode and display the map full screen, I can see almost the entire earth.  It's almost as if it cannot zoom out far enough to show the entire globe. I'm not getting the full sides or top/bottom of the map.  I wouldn't mind if there was grey or whatever outside my map (I don't need it to repeat).  I just want to get it so that the map scales with the smallest lat, long in the bottom left and the largest in the top right.  Does this make sense?

Comment: In case anybody finds this very old answer before the new (post iOS12 answer), then please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370852/how-to-display-entire-globe-in-mkmapview