# Can iOS 6+ MKMapView display whole world view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, zooming

Pre-iOS 6.0 I was able to display the full globe on an MKMapView (using the old google maps).  On iOS 6.0+ (using apple maps) I cannot zoom fully out (e.g. I cannot display USA and Russia in the same MKMapView at the same time).

Does anyone know if there is any code that allows this to happen?

Thanks, Charlie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a sample app and indeed, I could not zoom out as much as you wanted.

According to the accepted answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976639/why-isnt-my-mkmapview-zooming-out-as-much-as-it-should), it seems that you can't zoom out fully the way you want.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum zoom out you can get using MKCoordinateSpan is this:

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta = 180, .longitudeDelta = 360};
```

Any more latitudeDelta or longitudeDelta and you get a crash.

If you needed to see both the US and Russia at the same time, you could use 2 map views side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the MKMapView square, rather than fit the screen proportions.