# How to display entire globe in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, mkmapview

I am working on a map app and I want to enable user to zoom out to entire globe. I am using MKMapView. I saw that this feature is available in iOS map app.

Can anyone tell how can I achieve the same in my app.

[image: iPhone Map App Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MapKit Show Entire Globe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973645/mapkit-show-entire-globe)

Comment: Possible Third Party Library to get a globe in the "standard" style:
https://github.com/mousebird-consulting-inc/WhirlyGlobe

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is either 
(Since iOS 12, November 2018 at least)

```
mapView.mapType = .satelliteFlyover
```

or

```
mapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover
```

That's all.

Comment: It's like not so sad at all. If you pay attention to the dates, these answers were all posted before iOS 12 was released. If you have something new and better to say, don't go about discrediting everything and everyone else before that.

Comment: Super useful and correct. Still the same, Swift 5.5, December 2021. I hope other developers upvote your answer.

Comment: According to the documentation, both `.satelliteFlyover` and `.hybridFlyover` have been available since iOS 9.

Comment: Still works as of swift 5.9/Xcode 15.

Answer (score 1):

Change the map to Hybrid Flyover or Satellite Flyover
 and Enable 3D View from storyboard

Call this function from viewDidLoad 
updateMapToShowGlobe(location: mapView.centerCoordinate)

```
// MARK: Snippet to show full globe in 3d view
private func updateMapToShowGlobe(location :CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(130, 130)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    if( region.center.latitude > -90 && region.center.latitude < 90 && region.center.longitude > -180 && region.center.longitude < 180 ){
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```