# MKMapView (MapKit) - Trying to zoom out to see the entire globe

Tags: swift, mkmapview

Edit: I found a solution. MKMapView won't show the entire globe if you build it in Xcode's simulator, but it will if you build it on an actual device.

Existing versions of the question haven't worked - Need Swift 4, Xcode 10 solution:

I'm trying to zoom an MKMapView out to show the entire globe in my app. I can zoom out to see a *map* of the whole world, but not the entire *globe*.
​
Here's what I know:
-It has to be satellite, hybrid, satelliteFlyover, or hybridFlyover
-3D must be enabled.
​
Here is what I've tried:
-Adjusting the span of the region (no matter how big I make the span, it never zooms out enough to see the globe)
-Adjusting the altitude of the camera (no matter how high I make it, it never zooms out enough to see the globe)
​
I have googled and stack-overflowed, and I can't find any solutions that work. I am reduced to posting this question myself, violating my lurker principals, but I am totally stuck.

Here is some code I've tried from tutorials, etc. (several attempts commented out):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from   a nib.
    
    mapView.mapType = .standard
    mapView.isPitchEnabled = true
//        mapView.showsBuildings = true // displays buildings

    let eiffelTowerCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.85815, 2.29452)
    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: eiffelTowerCoordinates, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 100)    // sets the visible region of the map
    
    // create a 3D Camera
    let mapCamera = MKMapCamera()
    mapCamera.centerCoordinate = eiffelTowerCoordinates
    mapCamera.pitch = 45
    mapCamera.altitude = 50000000 // example altitude
    mapCamera.heading = 45
    
    // set the camera property
    mapView.camera = mapCamera
    
    
//        var ausCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -25.354917, longitude: 134.347407)
//        let camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: ausCenter, fromDistance: 300, pitch: 10, heading: 0)
//        mapView.camera = camera
    
//        var ausCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -25.354917, longitude: 134.347407)
//        var ausSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 5, longitudeDelta: 5)
//        var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: ausCenter, span: ausSpan)
//        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    
    
//        let camera = MKMapCamera()
//        camera.centerCoordinate = mapView.centerCoordinate
//        camera.pitch = 90.0
//        camera.altitude = 30000000
//        camera.heading = 0
//        mapView.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
    
//        var ausCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -25.354917, longitude: 134.347407)
//
////        mapView.setCenter(ausCenter, animated: true)
//
//        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 150, longitudeDelta: 150)
//        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: ausCenter, span: span)
//        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
//
//        //add an annotation
//        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
//        annotation.coordinate = ausCenter

//        annotation.title = "Australia"
//        annotation.subtitle = "Details Forthcoming"
//        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

}
```

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370852/how-to-display-entire-globe-in-mkmapview

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added code that I've tried above and I did attempt the ideas from the question you've linked, but it wouldn't work. Could anyone else get that solution to work from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370852/how-to-display-entire-globe-in-mkmapview