# How to view Apple Maps in a globe using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, maps

Looking for a solution I stumbled upon this post:
[How to display entire globe in MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370852/how-to-display-entire-globe-in-mkmapview/55895858#55895858)

I followed the steps from Tushar Katyal but could not see a GLOBE. At least not in the simulator view. How should I apply this to be able to see a globe?

I already have a 2D view, and with a pin that resembles a range, and want to project it on a globe to be more accurate.

The code applied is this:

Function in **viewDidLoad**:

```
updateMapToShowGlobe(location: mapView.centerCoordinate)
```

**declared function**:

```
// MARK: Snippet to show full globe in 3d view
private func updateMapToShowGlobe(location :CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(130, 130)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    if( region.center.latitude > -90 && region.center.latitude < 90 && region.center.longitude > -180 && region.center.longitude < 180 ){
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I need to have a "world view" for some results, and a closer view zooming in but also on the globe, since I have to center pins in very northern locations.